# Eclipse Plugin controls display

Tags: eclipse, layout, plugins, swt

I'm working with plugin creation for eclipse, and its running fine. It looks good in desktop screens but when its viewed in Laptop screens, half of the screen controls are hidden. Pls help me on this, guide me on how to use a particular layout that will adjust controls appearance on different screens.

Comment: Show is an [mcve]. Or read something line [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)

Comment: Thanks greg for your reply and sharing this resource.